# how to decode twice on xml schema via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, decode

I have xml schema but which contains &amp;lt; what I think is I need to decode this schema twice. But i'm not sure how to do this. Please help me to suggest on it.

```
Current Schema:
   <log>
        &lt;DataSet&gt;
          &lt;Data&gt;
            &amp;amp;lt;Table&amp;amp;gt;
                &amp;amp;lt;br&amp;amp;gt;    
                &amp;amp;lt;Name&amp;amp;gt;Tester&amp;amp;lt;/Name&amp;amp;gt;
                &amp;amp;lt;br&amp;amp;gt;
            &amp;amp;lt;/NewDataSet&amp;amp;gt;
          &lt;/Data&gt;
        &lt;/DataSet&gt;
    </log>
```

```
Expected Output:
    <log>
        <DataSet>
          <Data>
            <Table>
                    
                <Name>Tester</Name>
                
            </NewDataSet>
          </Data>
        </DataSet>
    </log>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 3.0? It's a lot easier in XSLT 3.0 than in older versions of XSLT

Comment: Yes i'm using 3.0

Comment: The content of `log` does not represent a well-formed XML. Even if you unescape  the escaped characters and close the `br` elements, you will still get an error because the start-tag `<Table>` has `</NewDataSet>` as its end-tag.

Comment: (a) This is not a schema, it is an XML instance document. (b) You actually need three levels of parsing, not two, because the contents of `log` have one extra layer of escaping, while the contents of `Table` have two. (c) Whoever produced this is incompetent. Do you really want to deal with such garbage? Far better to fix it at source.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you can get the expected output using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
<xsl:template match="log">
    <xsl:variable name="string" select="replace(replace(replace(., '&amp;amp;lt;br&amp;amp;gt;', ''), '&amp;amp;lt;', '&lt;'), '&amp;amp;gt;', '&gt;')"/>
    <log>
        <xsl:value-of select="$string" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </log>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this is not likely to do you any good - at least not with the given example - because the result is not a well-formed XML document and any attempt to use it as such will produce an error.

Note also that this handles only the problems shown in the given example. Who knows what other traps the actual input may contain.